# Do we have .net SDK for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, .net, sdk

is it possible to access iPhone file system from .net?
Do we have .net SDK for iPhone??
I am trying to write a program in .net to access the filesystem, basic operations like
switching off an iphone re-springing etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MonoTouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch) is a commercial product that will allow you to use C# to target iOS devices.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing available in this ilk for iPhone is [MonoTouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch).