# Detect incoming call iphone 5

Tags: c#, iphone, winforms

I have a question regarding the possibility of creating a winforms application in C#, which is able to detect incoming calls on an iphone.

Here is the scenario:

- the iphone is connected to the computer via a usb cable.
- whenever the phone rings I would like to be able to do the following:

  1. Retrive the phone number.
  2. Use the phone number in the winforms application, to search xml filer.
  3. Answer the phone via the application and play an automated voice message.

Is this even possible in C#? If so how could this be done and are there any libraries designed for interacting with an iphone using C#??

Thanks and regards.

Anders

Answer (score 3):

There are no SDK's that allow you to develop .NET apps that interact externally with the iPhone.

If you want to write an iPhone app, but are intimidated by the learning curve you could check out [MonoTouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153267/do-we-have-net-sdk-for-iphone).  It allows you to write iPhone\Android apps using C#.